# How to get PyCharm to display entire dataframes in the output console?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe that has 972 columns and I am trying to see all of it but the output has all the middle columns truncated.
I have tried the view variable in the debugger but it didn't work. I only got the first 30s columns. I have also tried the pandas display.width nor did it work. Can somebody help?
Here's my dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

**You can use this [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) in pandas:**

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

**Or you can do something like this:**

```
print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: Strange, I have the exact same problem, but pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint after the dataframe has been declared, then debug your code, check frames in debugger and for your desired dataframe select "view as dataframe".

You should have a SciView window in which the dataframe can be visualized with a nice layout

[Scientific mode in pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-tutorial.html)